# Largest commutative diagram actually used

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

This is a very soft-question so feel free to close it if doesn't fit. I was just wondering what is the largest commutative diagram that you have encountered? Here I am only counting commutative diagrams that are actually useful, e.g if you have an inverse system over a infinite direct poset you could if you wanted to draw out any number of objects but it wouldn't convey any new information compared two just drawing e.g three. It doesn't have to be "largest largest" diagram, any very big diagram is interesting.

Comment: I believe some weirdly large constructions - e.g. surreal numbers, which are a proper class, and in some sense a direct limit of all ordered fields, - can be described in an appropriate setting as a limit of a diagram which itself is a proper class. Does this count? :)

Comment: This is a comment not an answer because I can't speak to "largest."  But for some scary large diagrams, you can look here: https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540058441

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remarkably big diagrams (spanning multiple pages) appear in an attempt by Trimble to explicitly write down axioms for tetracategories, i.e. higher categories with up to 4 levels of morphisms. You can find them [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/tetracategories.html).